# How to re-open xCode Archive

Tags: xcode

XCode has buggered up my current project but I do have an archive of that project saved as an XArchive file. Is there any way to re-open this file as an Xcode project?

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you had a time machine backup of your Xcode project... but do you have a time machine backup?

Comment: Nope, but I did have a 2 day old backup and had to re-code some parts. Thanks anyways..